# Font size of tooltip in speeddialaction of React's Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to modify font size of tooltip shown on hovering over speeddialaction component?

Link to SpeedDial Component
https://material-ui.com/components/speed-dial/

Link to Speeddialaction component
https://material-ui.com/api/speed-dial-action/

Answer (score 5):

You can style tooltip by adding `TooltipClasses` prop to `SpeedDialAction` component. All that classes will be passed to `Tooltip` component, as it is written in `SpeedDialAction` [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/speed-dial-action/)

Here is modified example from [official docs](https://material-ui.com/components/speed-dial/):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SpeedDial from "@material-ui/lab/SpeedDial";
import SpeedDialIcon from "@material-ui/lab/SpeedDialIcon";
import SpeedDialAction from "@material-ui/lab/SpeedDialAction";
import FileCopyIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FileCopyOutlined";
import SaveIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Save";
import PrintIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Print";
import ShareIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Share";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const actions = [
  { icon: <FileCopyIcon />, name: "Copy" },
  { icon: <SaveIcon />, name: "Save" },
  { icon: <PrintIcon />, name: "Print" },
  { icon: <ShareIcon />, name: "Share" },
  { icon: <DeleteIcon />, name: "Delete" }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tooltip: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
});

function SpeedDials() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  function handleOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }
  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(!open);
  }

  return (
    <SpeedDial
      ariaLabel="SpeedDial example"
      icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
      open={open}
      direction="up"
      onBlur={handleClose}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onClose={handleClose}
      onFocus={handleOpen}
      onMouseEnter={handleOpen}
      onMouseLeave={handleClose}
    >
      {actions.map(action => (
        <SpeedDialAction
          key={action.name}
          icon={action.icon}
          tooltipTitle={action.name}
          onClick={handleOpen}
          TooltipClasses={classes}
        />
      ))}
    </SpeedDial>
  );
}

export default SpeedDials;
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rj4ho)

Comment: What 'this.props.classes' refer here to? How can we adapt this code to a function component?

Comment: @rahulshukla check now, I edited answer with functional component example.

Comment: Here is my code posted at [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/embed/twilight-fire-907mp) . And I am not able to incorporate the solution suggested.can you help me locate what's going wrong?

Comment: @rahulshukla remove "" from `fontSize: "30"` and `TooltipClasses={classes}` instead of `TooltipClasses={classes.tooltip}`, [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-forest-uwg02)

Comment: @@m51 Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @@m51 I updated for another case of tooltip where fontsize is not getting updated with css classes.Refer normal tooltip at [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-fire-907mp).All your help is much appreciated

Comment: @@m51 Similar question for styling tooltip component is posted at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885144/how-to-modify-font-size-style-of-tooltip-component) .If you would like to answer that

Comment: @@m51 code is no more working with ^4.0.0-alpha.31 release of @material-ui/lab.You can check it here https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pond-hye3n.Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

I corrected the code for SpeedADialAction Example.Code posted at [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pond-hye3n)