# How to modify font-size/style of Tooltip component?

Tags: material-ui

Not able to assign custom class to tooltip component in order to update the style of tooltip component

Tried by assigning to classes property

Posted at https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-fire-907mp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your own Tooltip with custom styles and then use it:

```
const TooltipWithBiggerFontSize = withStyles({
  tooltip: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
})(Tooltip)
```

As you already did with other components, eg: `DialogContent` or `DialogActions`.

Usage

```
<TooltipWithBiggerFontSize title="Custom Search">
  <Publish />
</TooltipWithBiggerFontSize>
```

BTW, your code is confusing. You are mixing functional and class components. Once, you are styling with `withStyles` once with `makeStyles`.
You should choose one method and stick to it. Here is styling [docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/). It will solve most of your problems.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-architecture-msnml)

Comment: Thanks for coming to rescue the issue here.Is there a gold standard when to use withStyles vs makeStyles? Underlying they all help us achieve same thing.

Comment: makeStyles returns a custom hook and you can only use hooks in function components (whereas CustomSearch is a class component). withStyles can be used with any kind of component, but it works by wrapping the component which can sometimes be more awkward to add to an existing component than the makeStyles/useStyles approach.