# When used together, TooltipClasses and FabProps are not working for SpeedDialAction in Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, speed-dial

While working on [SpeedDial component](https://material-ui.com/components/speed-dial/) of React's Material UI the following is needed:

1. Change the background color of speeddial button
2. Change the background color of speeddialactions
3. Change the font size of tooltip displayed on hover over speeddialactions

All this was done successfully earlier with the following dependencies at [sandbox URL for working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pond-hye3n) 
 - material-ui/core 4.1.3
 - material-ui/lab 4.0.0.alpha.18

But now with latest packages I have updated code posted here [sandbox URL for semi working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-leaf-fwt9q) where things are getting bumpy
 - material-ui/core 4.6.0
 - material-ui/lab 4.0.0.alpha.31
when hovered over speeddialaction there is an error that causes the SpeedDial to disappear. Error details can be seen in the console of [sandbox URL for semi working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-leaf-fwt9q)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3784705/m51
 last time you saved by providing a similar answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870940/font-size-of-tooltip-in-speeddialaction-of-reacts-material-ui/56885015#56885015 .Can you help or point who can be reached out for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug after I reported to material-ui community and has been fixed in alpha 32 release.Refer at [Issue and solution posted here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18312)